# Access SQL DB Managed Identity in Data Factory using Key Vault

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL DB using AD Authentication (Managed Identity) in Data Factory by saving the connection string in Azure Key Vault. I've setup the Managed Identity access in Azure SQL DB by providing the access to ADF (ADF name). I've stored the connection string in Key Vault in following formats but I was not successful.

Tried following formats of connection strings:

```
Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Authentication = 'Active Directory Interactive';

Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxx;User ID=DatafactoryName;Authentication = 'Active Directory Interactive';  -- Actual DatafactoryName

Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxx;User ID=MSI_ID;Authentication = 'Active Directory Interactive';   -- Actual MSI ID for the DataFactory

Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxx;User ID=a;Authentication = 'Active Directory Interactive';   -- Tried arbitrary value
```

I'm getting the following error

[image]

Comment: Hi, is the error solved now?

Comment: Yes, it's resolved now.

Comment: can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string should be:

```
Data Source=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Connection Timeout=30
```

The connection should like this:
[image]

Ref: [Managed identities for Azure resources authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#managed-identity) and [Reference secret stored in key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault#reference-secret-stored-in-key-vault)

Comment: This worked, thank you! I've followed only the connection string provided by you and then referred the connection string from keyvault rather than providing the connection string manually in the Linked Service

Comment: @ravitejaPuppala you're welcome! If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @ravitejaPuppala, hope you're doing well, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx
```